# Idiomatic way to build list with successive function calls on that list

Tags: python

It's a bit hard to explain in a concise title what I'm asking, so here's the explanation. I have a list of classes and these objects all contain their own set of data. The problem that I'm having is that I try to iterate over these objects and filter out data that is used in one of the objects that precedes the current one in the list. The code fragment looks like this:

```
objs = [list-of-objects]
used = set([])
for obj in objs:
    used = used.union(obj.callSomeFunc(used))
```

That callSomeFunc member returns a set of data that it has that does not intersect with the current used set.

This code works, but I don't really like it, and I can't believe that there isn't a better way to do this.

Comment: I don't personally see anything wrong with this code apart from the minor changes that [Sven Marnach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11225790/577088) suggests. But the fact that you "can't believe that there isn't a better way to do this" suggests to me that you have some specific improvement in mind. What would you consider an improvement on the above?

Comment: Guess it's a matter of taste, I just don't really like this way of thinking about my data. Anyway, I took Sven's advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I would change is to use `set.update()` instead of `set.union()`:

```
objs = [list-of-objects]
used = set()
for obj in objs:
    used.update(obj.callSomeFunc(used))
```

You *could* use `reduce()`, but I think this would harm readability.

**Edit**: Here's the code using `reduce()`:

```
used = reduce(lambda used, obj: used.union(obj.callSomeFunc(used)), objs, set())
```

Comment: I considered using reduce() but I do agree that it's slightly less readable.

Comment: Just changed the .union() to .update() and stuck with the original solution. Although slightly altered, the function actually takes 2 arguments, one of which is that used set, so I wrapped the whole thing in a functools.partial(). Makes for some clean looking code, but I still don't like it. Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the .update() direction :).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem then I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
objs=[1,19,4,3,1,3,5,1,5,6,7,8,9,18,8,6]
used=[]

for x in objs:
  if x not in used: #only choose that data that is not present in used
    used.append(x)
print(used)
```

output:

```
[1, 19, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also express the problem recursively - which may be more readable for some. :-)

```
def filter_list(used, remaining):
    if len(remaining) == 0:
        return used
    obj = remaining[0]
    return filter_list(used.append(obj.someFunc(used)), remaining[1:])
```